# Finding the smallest distance between a point and a set of points

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

I have a GPS dataset that corresponds to a route taken by a vehicle in a day. It consist of a set of coordinates. Then say I have a coordinate and I want to know how close this coordinate is to this route. So basically I am calculating the distance to each point on the route and get the minimum value. But I have to do this many times. If route has n points and there are m coordinates whose distance to the route must be calculated then complexity is m*n. I was just wondering if there could be a smarter way to this this?

Comment: Voronoi diagram maybe? It might be an overkill though.

Comment: I doubt there is faster way to achieve this than exhaustively testing each point

Comment: @NikosM. In $1$-$D$, the problem can be solved in $O((m+n) \log n)$ time. So, I hope there should be better algorithms in $2$-$D$.

Comment: A related [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901139/closest-point-to-a-given-point).

Comment: @InuyashaYagami KD tree looks promising

Comment: What is the goal of the distance computation? Are you trying to do [map matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching)? There is quite some research on that, and your approach may or may not be the best, depending on your application.

Comment: I don't understand what's *m* here?there are *n* points and just 2 axis right?ie we are talking about 2D distance, so what is m?or is it an *m-dimensional* space?

Comment: m is the number of coordinates whose distance to the route must be calculated. It is basically the number of times I have to do the said task. @ShAr

Comment: I guess then u can use the difference bet n1,n2 the node u was in & the node u r in now; maybe on a 1st thought subtract the difference from ur array of distances

Comment: No I just need to know how close some points are to a given set of points. There is no correlation between their patterns. @Discretelizard

Comment: Related question: [Finding the Voronoi cell a point belongs to](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87362/finding-the-voronoi-cell-a-point-belongs-to)

Comment: Build a kd-tree for the route’s points in $O(n \log(n))$ time and then for each of the $m$ coordinates, compute the nearest neighbor within the kd-tree. Each nearest neighbor call requires $O(\log(n))$ time, so the complete query portion of this work will run in $O(m \log(n))$. The overall runtime to do everything is then $O( (m+n) \log(n) )$, which beats the brute force result.